# C# Charting - Reasonble Large Data Set and Real-time

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, real-time, large-data-volumes

I'm looking for a C# WinForms charting component, either commercial or open source, that can handle relatively large data sets and be reasonable scalable with regards to chart rendering and updates. The number of data sets to be displayed would be around 30. There would be between 15 and 20 updates per second for each data set. A line chart component would be required for this.

Answer (score 3):

I have used [ZedGraph](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/) in the past for realtime stock charts with large histories.

It can be a little slow if the chart is very complex but found it to be very good and easy to expand (as open source) to do whatever custom formatting you need.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [Microsoft Chart Controls](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=130F7986-BF49-4FE5-9CA8-910AE6EA442C&displaylang=en) ?

Answer (score 0):

There are several chart controls from

- www.xceed.com
- www.infragistics.com
- www.teltrik.com

Maybe one of these will fulfill your requirements.