# Oscilloscope UserControl for .net

Tags: .net, winforms, zedgraph

I'm looking for a way to paint real time measurement data as a curve in a WinForms app. [Here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mgold/virtualoscilloscope08292005103442am/virtualoscilloscope.aspx?login=true&user=h0b0) is an example of something quite close to what I'm looking for. But is there something more modular out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any decent chart control will allow you to continuously update it.

See this question for some suggestions: [C# Charting - Reasonble Large Data Set and Real-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910790/c-charting-reasonble-large-data-set-and-real-time)

Answer (score 1):

The example you linked to is open sourced, therefore you can just take the parts you need and modify them accordingly.

You want to know if there is something "more modular", what is more modular than the source code?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the [Zedgraph-Wikipage](http://zedgraph.org/wiki/index.php?title=Display_Dynamic_or_Real-Time_Data) I was looking for.